# Event on change in select tag in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have my home.html as

```html
 <select name="PublicWords"> 
                    <option value="">All</option>
                    <option value="">Draft</option>
                    <option value="">Approved</option>
                    <option value="">Approved ZWNJ</option>
                    <option value="">Rejected</option>
                </select>
```

I would like to perform some action on change in this select tag in my django project
How can i perform this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `onchange` event handler on the html element. *(**Note:** I have changed `Name` to `id`.)*

```html
<select onchange="foo()" id="PublicWords"> 
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="">Draft</option>
    <option value="">Approved</option>
    <option value="">Approved ZWNJ</option>
    <option value="">Rejected</option>
</select>
```

Then also include the function call in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() {
    // function body here
    // for example
    d = document.getElementById("PublicWords").value;
    alert(d);
}
</script>
```

> Ensure that you have a value assigned to the particular option that closely relates to the option text.

Comment: but im using django,and how is it possible to use javascript in it